# Why 'delete' replaces value with undefined in arrays but in objects it is able to remove the property completely?

Tags: javascript

What differences in object and arrays cause this? Why is Object able to remove the element and array cannot? Does Object automatically makes a check to not display undefined values?

Comment: `delete arr[1]` - Now what value do you expect to see when you log `arr[1]`?

Comment: in JS, arrays are like shelves in a library. if you delete an element in one of the boxes, the library will not rebuild itself to rebuild itself by eliminating this box, it just deleted the element in the box. Otherwise you must use the Array.splice() method. But either way it will still be handled by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` **will** remove properties entirely from arrays.

```js
const array = [0,1,2];
delete array[1];
console.log("0" in array);
console.log("1" in array);
```

Since most tools that display an array for debugging purposes will not display them with explicit index values, any missing values will typically be rendered as undefined.

If they didn't then you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between these two examples:

```js
const sparse = [1,,2];
const full = [1,2];

console.log(sparse);
console.log(full);
```

If you want to shuffle the indexes of every subsequent item down the array, then you need to look at [the `splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).